# Explicit cursor pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql

Build a PL?SQL anonymous block that changes the credit limits for customers. Use and explicit cursor and the loop of your choice to accomplish the task. Also, keep trak of how many records were updaated and display the following message: "XX customer records were updated". make sure to commit all of hte records after your loop is finished. Below is a chart of the current credit limit and the new credit limit.

(old)10,000   (new)25,000,

(old)5,000    (new)10,000,

(old)7,000    (new)15,000,

(old)3,000    (new)5,000, (there are more in this table than just these 4).

Here's the code I have that obviously isn't working. Thank you in advance for your help. It's greatly appreciated.

```
    set serveroutput on
Declare
 Cursor c_credit_cursor is
  Select custid, creditlimit
  From customer
  where creditlimit = 10000
  or creditlimit = 5000 
  or creditlimit = 7000 
  or creditlimit = 3000
  and customer.custid = v_custid;
  v_creditlimit customer.creditlimit%TYPE;
  v_custid customer.custid%TYPE;
Begin
LOOP
open c_credit_cursor;
  Loop Fetch c_credit_cursor INTO v_custid, v_creditlimit;
  If v_creditlimit = 10000 then
    update c_credit_cursor
    set v_creditlimit = 25000;
  elsif v_creditlimit = 5000 then
    update c_credit_cursor
    set v_creditlimit = 10000;
  elsif v_creditlimit = 7000 then
    update c_credit_cursor
    set v_creditlimit = 15000;
  elsif v_creditlimit = 3000 then
    update c_credit_cursor
    set v_creditlimit = 5000;
  End If;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_custid ||' customer records were updated.');
  End Loop;
    commit;
    Exit When c_credit_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    Close c_credit_cursor;
  END Loop;
  End;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but was getting a syntax error with only one end loop.

Comment: Explicit cursors -- do they even exist outside of homework exercises?

Comment: I'm not sure. This as you guessed is a homework exercise that I have obviously tried to get working on my own, but ran into a wall. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code:

For a start, your cursor has the condition `customer.custid = v_custid`.  You want to run through all customers regardless of what their customer ID is: you're only interested in those that have one of the specified credit limits.  (In fact, later on in your code you are reading customer IDs out of cursor into `v_custid`, so it doesn't make sense to try to put `v_custid` back into the cursor.  I would recommend deleting this condition from your cursor.

Next, the reason you need two `END LOOP` statements is that you have two `LOOP` statements.  Each `LOOP` must be terminated with an `END LOOP`.    I don't see why you have the outer loop — you should only need one — so remove the first `LOOP` (just after `Begin`) and the second `END LOOP`.

The next problem is with the `update` statements.  Each of the `update c_credit_cursor` statements will give an error `table or view does not exist`.  The reason for this is that you can't update a cursor like this, you can only update a table.  The error is telling your that it couldn't find a table named `c_credit_cursor`.  You also need to specify the name of the column in the table to update: you can't use `v_creditlimit` as that's a local variable.  You want to use `creditlimit` instead.

There's two ways to fix up the `update` statements.  You can update the customer with the customer ID you read out of the cursor:

```
update customer
   set credit_limit = (new credit limit)
 where custid = v_custid;
```

Alternatively, you can update the current row of the cursor:

```
update customer
   set credit_limit = (new credit limit)
 where current of c_credit_cursor;
```

This second approach requires you to add `FOR UPDATE` to the end of your `CURSOR` declaration.

Next, you'll get an error about `EXIT` being used outside a loop.  You have an `Exit When` statement towards the bottom, but to be honest it's in the wrong place.  You really want your `Exit When` statement to be the first thing after the `Fetch` statement: if we tried to read data out of the cursor but got no more data, then there's no reason for us to stay in the loop any more, so we need to get out of it.

Finally, I'll point out that the line that prints out the number of customer records updated won't always print out the right output.  It's not printing out the number of records updated, it's only printing out the customer ID of the last record updated.  If you have five customer records in your database, with IDs 1 to 5, all five have credit limits that your loop would update, and the database happens to return the record with ID 5 last, then your code would output `5 customer records were updated`.  In that case, your code would have printed the correct answer, but that would only be by coincidence.  What would happen instead if the customers had IDs 1001 to 1005?

<strike>You'll need to add another local variable to count the number of records your cursor reads, and use that instead.</strike>

Comment: Thanks @Luke Woodward. I have to take care of my daughter real quick. I'll look over this shortly and provide adequate feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much @Luke Woodward. That was very constructive and well thought out. As you can tell, I don't really know that much. I've made all the edits you mentioned. For the records updated, I've changed that to the code below and will give that a try. Thank you for the help.   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (c_credit_cursor%ROWCOUNT ||' customer records were updated.');

Comment: I was getting drained and inadvertently put in two loop statements. I realized that about the update statements, but didn't know how to fix it. I was going to paste the error code as well, but didn't want to add details that weren't useful. I didn't realize that about the exit when statement, but it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @DerekPike: thanks for the feedback.  Error information is always useful on SO.  If you ask any future questions please include details of any errors you get.  To be honest, I didn't know about the `%ROWCOUNT` attribute of the cursor - I've learned something today!

Comment: Well now I feel accomplished that I taught you something @Luke Woodward. I will be sure to include any error information I get moving forward. Thanks again for all the help.